# Ext changes are not loading for liferay 6.2 with Maven build, ext-impl LoginUtil class

Tags: java, maven, liferay, liferay-6.2

I am creating ext plugin with liferay 6.2.10 EE.

with Ant build it is loading changes but with Maven build it is not loading changes.

I need to override class from ext-impl:
ext-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\login\util\LoginUtil.java

I was comparing war file from ant build to maven build, I found following difference in generated file ext-project-ext.xml.

A) In Ant built war file, it has following line in generated ext-project-ext.xml

```
 <file>ext-impl/classes/com/liferay/portlet/login/util/LoginUtil.class</file>
```

but with maven built war file, above line is not present in ext-project-ext.xml.
Do we have any way to declare overridden class in any configuration file in case of maven.

B) With Ant built war file LoginUtil.class is present under ext-impl.jar, but with maven built war file ext-impl.jar is not having loginUtil.class.
can we fix this by any configuration ?

both above A and B are relative and with anyone configuration it may fix both issue.

Because of above 2 difference, It is not loading the changes.

I have posted this question in liferay forum as well to get possible answer. thanks. https://liferay.dev/en/ask/questions/development/ext-changes-are-not-loading-for-liferay-6-2-with-maven-build-loginutil

Regards,
Brijesh

Comment: [Please note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)

Comment: @OlafKock, thanks for informing, I have updated details with post from liferay forum as well..